# Set XHR Request Timeout longer than 60 seconds: HTTP2

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fetch-api

Is there any way, on modern Chrome, FF, Safari, to set a timeout for and XHR request that's longer than 60 seconds?

The [docs here](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/apis/xhr/XMLHttpRequest/timeout/) state:

> If you set an XMLHttpRequest time-out value that is larger than the network stack’s time-out value, the network stack will time out first and the ontimeout event will not be raised.

This "Network stack time-out value" is not very well documented, but a quick test shows it starts to fail above 60 seconds.

So, setting an XHR request timeout to 65 seconds will give you `NETWORK REQUEST FAILED` in Chrome, if it takes any longer than 60.

There are a number of situations where this could be a problem, for example:

- Slow internet connections
- Slow backend requests hosted by third parties where a cache layer may not be viable

I've also looked at the Keep-Alive header, but apparently that's only HTTP1 and doesn't work anymore.

There's a ten year old thread about this, but I am not sure if an XHR request is treated any differently than the initial request to a site, and whether there's any sort of programmatic way around this.

https://superuser.com/questions/633648/how-can-i-change-the-default-website-connection-timeout-in-chrome/633649#633649

Comment: Reason you have not adopted the use of fetch?